# How do I print a line in one file based on a corresponding value in a second file?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have two files: 
File1:

```
A
B
C
```

File2:

```
2
4
3
```

I would like to print each line in file1 the number of times found on the corresponding line of file2, and then append each line to a separate file.

Desired output:

```
A
A
B
B
B
B
C
C
C
```

Here is one of the approaches I have tried:

```
touch output.list
paste file1 file2 > test.dict
cat test.dict
```

```
A       2
B       4
C       3
```

```
while IFS="\t" read -r f1 f2
do
   yes "$f1" | head -n "$f2" >> output.list
done < test.dict
```

For my output I get a bunch of lines that read:

```
head: : invalid number of lines
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What does test.dict actually look like? Sounds like the problem is with joining the two files rather than your general approach.

Comment: test.dict has two columns where the first column reads: A tab 2 new line B tab 4 new line C tab 3. The tabs and new lines are not actually there.

Comment: You should modify the question to add the file rather than trying to fit it into a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `IFS` to an [ANSI-C quoted string](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html) or remove `IFS` (since the default value already contains tab).
You can also use a process substitution and prevent the temporary file.

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r f1 f2; do
  yes "$f1" | head -n "$f2"
done < <(paste file1 file2) > output.list
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the output of `paste` and use a c-style for loop in replacement of `yes` and `head`.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read -r first second; do
  for ((i=1;i<=second;i++)); do
    printf '%s\n' "$first"
  done
done < <(paste file1.txt file2.txt)
```

If you think that the output is correct add

```
| tee file3.txt
```

with a white space in between the command substitution to redirect the output to a `stdout` and the output file which is file3.txt

```
done < <(paste file1.txt file2.txt) | tee file3.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) 1-liner

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[++i]=$0;next}{for(j=0;j<$0;j++)print a[FNR]}' File1 File2
A
A
B
B
B
B
C
C
C
```